# PHP: POST not working While GET is working

Tags: php

I've got a strange problem (I've tried to google that and search it in here with no luck) the thing is that when I try to POST data I get absolutely no data POSTED and if I change form method to GET and then echo out that variable - it works perfect...

Yesterday everything seemed to work, today I've added only this function:

```
header("Location: account_activation.php");
```

which has really nothing to do with it, yesterday registration fields worked 100% fine with no errors, so here's the code, PHP part:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_POST['register_email'] != ""))
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
?>
```

HTML part:

```
<form action="z_unity_index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="email"    maxlength="100" required id="register_email"    value="<?php echo $register_email ?>"    name="register_email"    placeholder="E-Mail (3-100 Characters)" />
    <input type="text"     maxlength="20"  required id="register_username" value="<?php echo $register_username ?>" name="register_username" placeholder="Username (6-20 Characters, A-Z and 0-9)" />
    <input type="password" maxlength="100" required id="register_password"                                          name="register_password" placeholder="Password (6-100 Characters)" />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="register_submit" />
</form>
```

I have deleted all unnecessary data and haven't included further data in if function, because the thing is that I'm not getting past it, because the POST data that I get is empty...

Comment: it's not id that is passing POST to file, add `name="register_email"` to your input field

Comment: @AleksandarVasić The name attributes are there, just scroll to the right a little :)

Comment: where did you place `header`? Are you posting form values to same script?

Comment: @ApulGupta header is inside if function, where all those dots .... are, and yes I'm posting to same file(it works with GET so that says already that it's the same file)

Comment: Can you place `var_dump($_POST);` in your php code to see what containts in `$_POST`?

Comment: @Comodo I've got "array(0) { }" when I POSTED the form data

Comment: If you look at the request in your developer console (in chrome, firebug in ff) are the POST values sending?

Comment: seems your path `z_unity_index.php` in form action is wrong. Also, can you edit your question and place full code of your `z_unity_index.php` with  `header("Location: account_activation.php");` call

Comment: @Comodo Path is 100% right, at the header function I'm redirecting to another page and that's how it is supposed to work, but that code doesn't even run, because $_POST['register_email'] is empty

Comment: @chris85 under which section I should be looking for requests tab? Because I've got Elements, Resources, Network, Sources, Timeline, Profiles, Audits, Console (in chrome)

Comment: `$_POST['register_email']` is not empty. It's unexists. You should show us full code. Unless, we all can only sugest what the error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think that the problem is your `header("Location: account_activation.php");`.

Why?
Because it means that you perform a `302 Redirection`. Both `301` and `302` redirections **do not preserve POST data**, which is intended feature. Why does `GET` work then? Because `GET` values (parameters) are just part of `query-string`, which usually follows redirections.

So yes, it has everything to do with this. At least unless I'm mistaken, which *may* be true :)

Comment: I was basically 100% sure that that's not the case so I've tried commenting it out and it... WORKED, and now I've understood that in account_activation.php I've another redirection with if function, that says if some GET variables are not POSTED(which isn't) it redirects me to the page that I'm struggling on and that's why it looks like nothing has happened, sorry for wasting your time guys with this strange problem which was my own mistake, THANK YOU!

Comment: @Donny123 don't worry, just learn on your mistakes :) redirections can be come really big mess, so I would recommend to use them only as last resort (for example as `404`, `410` or `403` status codes or `301` permanent redirections for moved pages)